# Why does my Python script take too much time to execute?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large Excel spreadsheet of astronomical observation data that comes from a SQL database query.

The data is sorted by `galaxyID` and there are about 70 columns and 5000+ rows.

90% of the data are just duplicates and I need to find which columns are causing the duplicates.

For example, I might have a row that is repeated 50 times where all the data is the same except for one column.

SO I have this Python program below that is supposed to list all the column headers that are causing duplicates for each `galaxyID`.

Like if `galaxyID 0473788` has 30 rows exccept 2 columns causing dupes, I'd like the Python script to list something like:

`galaxyID 0473788: unique column(s) causing duplicates --- observationTimeId (5874), locationName('Juno Mountain').`

But when I run the program it seems to go into an infinite loop printing out every single row in the Excel Spreadsheet.

Does anyone see anything that's wrong?

Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd

def find_unique_rows_by_ID(file_path):

    df = pd.read_excel(file_path, engine='openpyxl')

    df.sort_values(by='galaxyID', inplace=True)

    grouped = df.groupby('galaxyID')

    unique_rows_by_ID = {}

    for ID, group in grouped:
        unique_rows = group.drop_duplicates(keep=False)

        unique_rows_list = []
        for index, row in unique_rows.iterrows():
            unique_data = {
                'row': row.to_dict(),
                'unique_columns': list(row.index)
            }
            unique_rows_list.append(unique_data)

        unique_rows_by_ID[ID] = unique_rows_list

    return unique_rows_by_ID

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_path = "astronomy_observation_data.xlsx"
    unique_rows = find_unique_rows_by_ID(file_path)

    for ID, unique_rows_list in unique_rows.items():
        print(f"galaxyID: {ID}")
        for unique_data in unique_rows_list:
            print("Unique Row:", unique_data['row'])
            print("Unique Columns:", unique_data['unique_columns'])
            print("--------------------")
```

Comment: This can't go into an infinite loop. All the `for-in` loops are bounded by the length of the thing they're looping over.

Comment: @Barmar oh ok, bad english im sorry, I mean it takes a very long time

Comment: Are any of the results that it prints not actually duplicates?

Comment: @Barmar it's printing out every column and every cell for each row in the Excel spreadsheet. It's a giant list.....I only need the duplicate column(s)/value(s) for each `galaxyID`.   It's giving me way too much...I am not sure how to get what I want. :(

Comment: Can you add some example data and the expected result?

Comment: I don't see any attempt in your code to skip rows that aren't duplicated, or to show only the different columns in the duplicate rows.

Comment: The title should be changed, an endless loop is different than poor performance.  I'm not going to down-vote the question, but it's misleading to those of us that came here to help. Consider: "Why is looping over my pandas dataframe taking so long?"

Comment: Do you mind to add a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got the question right, you want to find the columns in each group that are different and thus cause the duplications. So we need to delete the columns whose values are unique in each group. In this case, something like this should work:

```
def find_unique_rows_by_ID(file_path):

    df = pd.read_excel(file_path, engine='openpyxl')

    df.sort_values(by='galaxyID', inplace=True)

    grouped = df.groupby('galaxyID')

    unique_rows_by_galaxyID = {}

    for ID, group in grouped:
        galaxyID = group['galaxyID'].iloc[0]
        unique_rows = group
        for col in group.columns:
            if len(group[col].unique()) == 1:
                unique_rows.drop(col, inplace=True, axis=1)

        unique_rows_by_galaxyID[galaxyID] = list(
            unique_rows.columns.values)
    print(unique_rows_by_galaxyID)
    return unique_rows_by_galaxyID
```

Comment: Is there a good way to format it?  The output is very confusing to try and read. thanks!

Comment: I've edited the code so now the key of the dictionary is the galaxyIDs and the value is a list of columns that have different values.

Answer (score 1):

We've got a couple of things to look at.
Firstly, the original example script would likely list all columns of unique rows as unique columns, so a comparison would need to be added to adjust that to only show the specific columns that caused a given row to be unique.

On a similar note, the line

```
unique_rows = group.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

requires that rows be 100% identical in order to get dropped, so if there is even a single column of unique values (such as timestamp) then that would need to be removed, otherwise ALL rows will be "unique." It would not be an infinite loop, but it would print all rows.

So, If we take this example set:

[image: example data set starting with galaxyID followed by other column names]

where Unique rows are 2, 6, 8, 11, 5, 16, 
and unique columns are all column_3 except for row 16, which has two unique columns,
and we hand it to this script:

```python
import pandas as pd

def find_unique_rows_by_ID(file_path):

    df = pd.read_excel(file_path, engine='openpyxl')

    df.sort_values(by='galaxyID', inplace=True)

    grouped = df.groupby('galaxyID')

    unique_rows_by_ID = {}

    for ID, group in grouped:
        unique_rows = group.drop_duplicates(keep=False)

        unique_rows_list = []
        for index, row in unique_rows.iterrows():
            original_row_number = row.name + 2
            non_unique_columns = []

            duplicated_rows = group[group.duplicated(keep=False)]
            for column in row.index:
                if any(row[column] != other_row[column] for _, other_row in duplicated_rows.iterrows()):
                    non_unique_columns.append(column)

            unique_data = {
                'original_row_number': original_row_number,
                'unique_columns': non_unique_columns,
                'unique_column_values': {col: row[col] for col in non_unique_columns}
            }
            unique_rows_list.append(unique_data)

        unique_rows_by_ID[ID] = unique_rows_list

    return unique_rows_by_ID

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_path = "astronomy_observation_data.xlsx"
    unique_rows = find_unique_rows_by_ID(file_path)

    for ID, unique_rows_list in unique_rows.items():
        print(f"\ngalaxyID: {ID}")
        for unique_data in unique_rows_list:
            print("Original Row Number:", unique_data['original_row_number'])
            print("Unique Columns:", unique_data['unique_columns'])
            print("Unique Column Values:", unique_data['unique_column_values'])
            print("--------------------")
```

We will get the following output:

```
galaxyID: GAL_1
Original Row Number: 2
Unique Columns: ['column_3']
Unique Column Values: {'column_3': 'example_1F'}
--------------------
Original Row Number: 6
Unique Columns: ['column_3']
Unique Column Values: {'column_3': 'example_1G'}
--------------------

galaxyID: GAL_2
Original Row Number: 8
Unique Columns: ['column_3']
Unique Column Values: {'column_3': 'example_2F'}
--------------------
Original Row Number: 11
Unique Columns: ['column_3']
Unique Column Values: {'column_3': 'example_2G'}
--------------------

galaxyID: GAL_3
Original Row Number: 5
Unique Columns: ['column_3']
Unique Column Values: {'column_3': 'example_3F'}
--------------------
Original Row Number: 16
Unique Columns: ['column_2', 'column_3']
Unique Column Values: {'column_2': 'example_3G', 'column_3': 'example_3G'}
--------------------
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: I think this solution might be better, but for some reason, on my machine, it is incredibly slow....like I left it running for 10 minutes and it still didn't finish.

Comment: How many rows and columns are we looking at?